# not deterministic behavior with priorities

Tags: esper

I  have developed an application using priorities that I have verified using http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html, with a set of input events.

Using a Java environment with esper 5.3, and using always the same input data,   I find two scenarios:

- If I configure priorities using config.getEngineDefaults ().
  GetExecution (). SetPrioritized (true) and  I subscribe to the sentence
  xxx, every time I run the application, it  produces a different
  number of subscriber activations of the sentence xxx.
- If I don't configure priorities, every time I run the application
  always produces the same number of subscriber activations

In the case of setting the priorities (the first option)  what reason can be behind this not  deterministic behavior?
Any kind of help will be very appreciated

Comment: Can you please clarify what "sentence xxx" could mean? It may be best you give the EPL and code.

Comment: The cloud application has the default configuration and should have prioritized processing disabled because its not the default.